# What exactly is a RID in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I see educational videos and articles where non-clustered indexes explained and mentioned RIDs that are used to refer from a non-clustered index to data in a heap. In a case when there is a clustered index then records in a non-clustered index refer to index key values of the clustered index.

Could someone please explain in detail, if possible, with a graphical representation, what are the RIDs in SQL Server, where they are stored, what is their structure, what exactly are both sides of the reference? I mean to give a definitive answer that has all the necessary information about the RIDs in SQL Server.

Here is a good example with a graphical explanation of a B-tree with a clustered index: https://www.essentialsql.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/SQL-Index.jpg?ezimgfmt=ng:webp/ngcb2 It would be nice to see some explanation of RIDs in a detailed representation like this.

Comment: [This page on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) explains what a heap is, and also includes: *individual rows are identified by reference to a row identifier (RID) consisting of the file number, data page number, and slot on the page*. So a RID is a combination of three numbers - file no, date page no, and slot no on that page

Comment: You might also review the [SQL Server Index Architecture and Design Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide). A RID is a physical pointer that uniquely identifies a row whereas a clustered index key is a logical pointer that uniquely identifiers a row in a table. These are stored in non-clustered index leaf nodes as the row locator.